# What will be the result when we move a magnet aligned vertically towards a coil whose area vector is aligned horizontally?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

According to Lenz's law, when we bring a magnet with one of its poles facing towards the area vector of a coil, an emf is induced in such a way that the pole is repelled. Im curious about what will happen when we bring a **magnet aligned vertically** towards a **coil whose area vector is aligned horizontally**? Will an emf be induced? What will be the polarities of the coil at A and B?  If a polarity is observed at a and b wont it be not aligned with the turn of the coil? If so how does that induction work?[image: t]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing the center of the magnet in along the axis of the coil would be the same as moving the coil toward the magnet.  The magnetic force on free electrons near the top of a tight coil would be in the same direction as those near the bottom.  The forces would cancel giving no net emf in the coil, no current, and no reaction force on the magnet. On the other hand, in an open coil, like the one in the sketch, the forces at the top would be slightly larger (each loop is closer to the magnet at the top). This could result in some current (If the ends of the coil are shorted).